# The Add Feature Button is not present on toolbar in QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis-3, toolbar

This may sound crazy, but I do not have an Add Feature button on my toolbar in QGIS 3.6.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Version 3.6, installed april 19 2019

Comment: Please edit the question to include the version info from your comment. Also include -- did you have this button before the upgrade? Which toolbars are open/active? Have you tried customizing the toolbars? https://www.gislounge.com/tour-of-qgis-mastering-qgis/

Comment: This is a new install of Version 3.6, not an upgrade.  Standard toolbars.  i have checked every other toolbar available.

Comment: Are the digitizing toolbar or advanced digitizing toolbars enabled? Described here: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#digitizing-an-existing-layer

Comment: This info solved my issue.  Thank you.  Former ArcMAP user, switching over and getting lost during first project

Comment: No problem! Primarily ArcMap myself. :) I'll add as answer; kindly accept when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

The Add Feature buttons are found on the Digitzing and/or Advanced Digitizing toolbars in QGIS 3.6, per https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#digitizing-an-existing-layer. Double-check that these toolbars are enabled.